# Proper preg_match for getting the end of a string

Tags: php, regex

I am having trouble with regular expressions my goal is to get the end of a string them put it on an if else statement. So for example I have a string of `2017_annualoff` I am using my preg_match to sample off the `annualoff` in an if else statement just like this.

```
else if (preg_match("/^(.*?)\annualoff/", $request->filters['types.created_at']))  {
            return "Hello annual off";
            // $trimmedFilter =  str_replace('_annualoff', '', $request->filters['types.created_at']);
            // $splitYear = $trimmedFilter;
            // $filtered_table = $filtered_table->where('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . '2016-11-16' . '%');
          }
```

But it won't go through in that block while my other code blocks go through, here's the rest of the if else statement.

```
if(preg_match("/^(.*?)\monthlyoff/", $request->filters['types.created_at'])) {

} else if (preg_match("/^(.*?)\quarteroff/", $request->filters['types.created_at'])) {

} else if (preg_match("/^(.*?)\annualoff/", $request->filters['types.created_at']))  {
            return "Hello annual off";
}
```

I tried making annualoff preg match to something simple like "99" then the sample string 2017_99, and it went through. So I think there must be something wrong with my regular expression. **Can you help solve this? Or why it won't go through? What's a proper regular expression for this?** Meanwhile when I am using a different string it goes through.

Comment: (a) Is it supposed to be the _end_ of the string? If so, you should include `$` at the end of the expression. (b) Why is there a backslash `\` before the `a`?

Comment: What are you doing with the backslashes? `\a`, `\q`, `\m`?

Comment: yes it's always supposed to be the end of the string. I am sorry guys I found the regex on the internet and it claimed to "read the end of the string" to sample it off. I thought the backslashes do nothing and just separate the word I am sampling it off, atleast I thought that's what it did.

Comment: You also could do this all in one regex. `/(monthly|quarter|annual)off$/`, then use the third parameter of preg_match to know what was matched. The `\a` is a special character. Many backslashes pairings do special things.

Comment: @user827391012 the post which you have accepted will work for `Hello this is very bad of monthlyoff`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$` to match characters at the end of the string

```
<?php

$created_at = trim($request->filters['types.created_at']);

if (preg_match("/monthlyoff$/", $created_at)) { }

else if (preg_match("/quarteroff$/", $created_at)) { }

else if (preg_match("/annualoff$/", $created_at)) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:** `^[\d]{4}\_monthlyoff$` This will match `4digits` then `_` then your string

**Example:** `2017_monthlyoff`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(preg_match("/^[\d]{4}\_monthlyoff$/", $request->filters['types.created_at'])) {

} else if (preg_match("/^[\d]{4}\_quarteroff$/", $request->filters['types.created_at'])) {

} else if (preg_match("/^[\d]{4}\_annualoff$/", $request->filters['types.created_at']))  {
            return "Hello annual off";
}
```

Comment: @chris85 which character class you are talking about sir?

Comment: The `[\d]`s in each regex. `\d` will work the same. The underscore also doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: yes, right usually i put these so that OP can add any character if he want add more validation, My expression will also work fine... but thanks alot mann.. :)